# Renamed Django directory root - ImportError: cannot import name 'python_implementation' from 'platform'

Tags: django

I renamed my project and my directory using Pycharm refactor functions, and now it's broken. I changed all the dependencies I could find, however there seems to be some funky stuff going on with the error and I absolutely cannot figure it out.
The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user1/Projects/platform_back/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/user1/Projects/platform_back/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Projects\platform_back\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user1\Projects\platform_back\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Projects\platform_back\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 244, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "C:\Users\user1\Projects\platform_back\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 37, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\user1\Projects\platform_back\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.core.management.commands.runserver import (
  File "C:\Users\user1\Projects\platform_back\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import (
  File "C:\Users\user1\Projects\platform_back\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 14, in <module>
    from wsgiref import simple_server
  File "C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 17, in <module>
    from platform import python_implementation
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_implementation' from 'platform' (C:\Users\user1\Projects\platform_back\platform\__init__.py)
```

It seems to be calling directories from outside the virtual environment, but I don't understand if this is intentional or not.

**init**.py:

```
from .dev import *
```

dev.py:

```
from .settings import *

DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

MIDDLEWARE.append('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')
INSTALLED_APPS.append('debug_toolbar')
INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1', 'localhost')
```

I know I could probably just recreate the whole app with a new name but I feel like there's a lesson to be learned here. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call your project `platform` – that's a name reserved by [this built-in module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/platform.html#module-platform).

The last lines of the traceback,

```
  File "wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 17, in <module>
    from platform import python_implementation
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_implementation' 
             from 'platform' (C:\Users\user1\Projects\platform_back\platform\__init__.py)
```

are `wsgiref`, the WSGi server implementation module (also a built-in) trying to import `platform.python_implementation()`, but since your module is also called `platform`, this fails.

Comment: this is the problem, I had refactored all references to platform within the venv as well, it took a bit of work but it's all fixed now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you rename your directory, you should change the `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` imports as well. Most likely those files are still looking at the old imports.